# I am trying to scrape toll data using python from(https://www.expresslanes.com/map-your-trip) ,but i don't know how to scrape data using XHR

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Website Link:- [Website](https://www.expresslanes.com/map-your-trip)
I want all the combination of every entry point and every exit point -suppose (Jones Branch Drive/Route 123) and (495 Express End (near MD))will give me a combination of these two routes. That's how i want all the combinations of entry points and exit points and store it into excel sheet .below is the reference image In toll data ,these are some things that are present in json format. [You can view data which is given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JWqx.png)You can view data which is given below

Comment: Did you forget to add your Python code to your question? Also, I believe that XHR is specific to JavaScript. Having said that, you could probably use either of *scrapy*, *selenium* or *requests* in Python

Comment: Where is the code? What is the url?

Comment: [Website link](https://www.expresslanes.com/map-your-trip)I haven't mentioned any code because I don't know How to approach it . Part of the website which gives entry and exit point combination seems to be be static but the part which gives the toll prices seems to be dynamic as the prices constantly change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The website serves the pricing data via Fetch/XRH, so you could scrape those using python library requests.

To see the request, inspect the page, then navigate to Network -> Fetch/XRH and you would see request, request headers and response.

Here is the example code to fetch prices:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.expresslanes.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.expresslanes.com/map-your-trip',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.expresslanes.com/maps-api/infra-price-confirmed-all', headers=headers)

# Load the data
data = json.loads(response.content)

# Get the dataframe of required values from the resulted json
df = pd.json_normalize(data['response'])

df.head()
```

This results in:

[image: resulted dataframe]